# can I add an image header in navigation drawer layout

Tags: android, android-studio, header, navigation-drawer, expandablelistadapter

how can i add an image header to my navigation drawer layout like this one

[image]

and this is my code :
MainActivity.java

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.House_Fragment.Garage_Fragment;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.House_Fragment.Hall_Fragment;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.House_Fragment.Kitchen_Fragment;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.AccountPreference;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.DialogChangeAccount;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.DialogChangeCity;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.DialogSettingsApp;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.DialogSupport;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.CityPreference;
import com.webileapps.navdrawer.menu.Settings.DialogueConnexion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
     implements         DialogChangeCity.dialogDoneListenerCity,
    DialogChangeAccount.dialogDoneListenerAccount,
    DialogSettingsApp.dialogDoneListenerSett,
    DialogSupport.dialogDoneListenerSupp,
            DialogueConnexion.dialogDoneListenerConn {
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayoutR;
ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
ExpandableListView mDrawerListR;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggleR;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitleR;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private CharSequence mTitleR;
List<Model> listDataHeader;
List<Model> listDataHeaderR;
HashMap<Model, List<Model>> listDataChild;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapterR;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mTitleR = mDrawerTitleR = getTitle();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListR = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

    prepareListData();
    prepareListDataRight();
    // set a custom shadow that overlays 
                  the main content when the drawer opens
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, 
                 listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listAdapterR = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeaderR,null);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
   // mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.up_24,GravityCompat.END);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
   /* mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mRoomTitles));*/
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    mDrawerListR.setAdapter(listAdapterR);
    //mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(
                           new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerListR.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.
                             OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView  expandable
                           ListView, 
                  View view, int i, long l) {
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    DialogSettingsApp dialogSettingsApp =
                                     new DialogSettingsApp();
                    dialogSettingsApp.
                       show(getFragmentManager(),"diagSett");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DialogChangeAccount dialogChangeAccount =
                               new DialogChangeAccount();
                    dialogChangeAccount.
                            show(getFragmentManager(),"diagA");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DialogChangeCity dialogChangeCity = 
                        new DialogChangeCity();
                    dialogChangeCity.show(getFragmentManager(),"diagC");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DialogSupport dialogSupport = new DialogSupport();
                    dialogSupport.show(getFragmentManager(),"diagSupp");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    DialogueConnexion dialogueConnexion =
                                  new DialogueConnexion();
                    dialogueConnexion.
              show(getFragmentManager(),"diagConn");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.
                               OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            Fragment frg = null;
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content, PageSlidingHomeFragment.newInstance()
                   , PageSlidingHomeFragment.TAG).commit();
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(groupPosition, true);
                    mDrawerList.setSelection(groupPosition);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:
                    frg = new Kitchen_Fragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    frg = new Garage_Fragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    frg = new Hall_Fragment();
                    break;
            }
            if (frg != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content, frg).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(groupPosition, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(groupPosition);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggleR=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.down_24,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    ){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitleR);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, /*
                         nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open, /* 
                         "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close /* 
                        "close drawer" description for accessibility */

    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggleR);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu){
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater 
                   inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home: {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListR);
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.action_contact:{
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListR)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListR);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerListR);

            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void showInputDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Change city");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Go", new 
              DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            changeCity(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void changeCity(String city) {
    new CityPreference(this).setCity(city);
}

// The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
/*private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view
                      , int   position,long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
*/

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content,
                            PageSlidingHomeFragment.newInstance(),
                            PageSlidingHomeFragment.TAG).commit();
            break;
    }
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

private void prepareListDataRight(){
    listDataHeaderR = new ArrayList<Model>();

    listDataHeaderR.add(new Model(R.drawable.settings_24,
    "App Settings"));
    listDataHeaderR.add(new Model(R.drawable.edit_user_24,
    "Update Account"));
    listDataHeaderR.add(new Model(R.drawable.edit_24, "Change City"));
    listDataHeaderR.add(new Model(R.drawable.quest_24, "Support"));
    listDataHeaderR.add(new Model(R.drawable.
  ic_action_user,    "Disconnection"));
}
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<Model>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<Model, List<Model>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add(new Model(R.drawable.home24, "Home"));
    listDataHeader.add(new Model("Rooms"));
    listDataHeader.add(new Model(R.drawable.kitchen_24, "Kitchen"));
    listDataHeader.add(new Model(R.drawable.garage_24, "Garage"));
    listDataHeader.add(new Model(R.drawable.room_24, "Hall"));

    // Adding child data
    List<Model> home = new ArrayList<Model>();
    home.add(new Model(R.drawable.settings_24, "Settings"));
    home.add(new Model(R.drawable.devices_24, "Devices"));
    home.add(new Model(R.drawable.weather_24, "Weather"));
    List<Model> rooms = new ArrayList<Model>();
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.bed_c_24, "1sr Child room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.bed_c_24, "2sd Child room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.bedroom_24, "Parents room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.hotel_24, "Guests room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.dining_room_24, "Dining room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.livingroom_24, "Living room"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.office_24, "Office"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.bathroom_24, "Bathroom 1st floor"));
    rooms.add(new Model(R.drawable.bathroom_24, "Bathroom 2nd floor"));


    // Header, Child data

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), rooms);


}


@Override
public void onDone(String text, boolean state) {

    if (state) {
        changeCity(text);
        //this.recreate();
        restartSelf();
    }
}

private void restartSelf() {
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)  gettSystemService(Context.
  ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar.getInstance()
 .getTimeInMillis() 
 + 1000, // one second
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(),
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onDoneA(String login, String opwd, String npwd) {
    if(login!="" && opwd!="" && npwd!=""){
        changeAccount(login,opwd,npwd);
    }
}

private void changeAccount(String login, String opwd, String npwd) {
    new AccountPreference(this).setAccountL(login);
    new AccountPreference(this).setAccountOP(opwd);
    new AccountPreference(this).setAccountNP(npwd);
}

@Override
public void onDone() {
    int x = 0;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas
     .android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/abs__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<Model> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<Model, List<Model>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Model> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<Model, List<Model>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this.
   _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 final Model childText = (Model) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    ImageView IconListChild = (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById
                  (R.id.item_icon_child);
    IconListChild.setImageResource(childText.getIcon());
    txtListChild.setText(childText.getTitle());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int i=0;
    switch (groupPosition) {
        case 1:
        i= this._listDataChild.get
  (this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
            break;
        default:
            i=0;
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

@Override
public Model getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Model headerTitle = (Model) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    ImageView IconListHeader = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById
           (R.id.item_icon_group);
    IconListHeader.setImageResource(headerTitle.getIcon());
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: Yes definitely you can.

Comment: Add the image as a link

Comment: @Mohamed: Are you not using fragment for the navigation drawer? if yes can please post the xml of the fragment.

Comment: no I'm not using a fragment for the navigation drawer just i have drawer_list_item which i had <textview> to describe my items menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Navigation Drawer layout xml file. Above drawerView and inside your parent layout add an image view as shown below:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="respective_source_of_image" />
```

This should be sufficient. Hope this helps.

Use Recycler View to create a navigation drawer. Recycler view is used most now. In your navigation drawer fragment have your layout file as shown below. This make you achieve your objective:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.ms.t.tms.NavigationDrawerFragment">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="respective_image_src" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to add this in your navigation drawer fragment xml.

Comment: nope it doesn't work and this image found in the center of the screen and not in the header of the list any help !!!

Comment: Can you update your xml file with new one. You can add rules to get it as a header. Please update the post with your new XML file.

Comment: just minute , what mean may navigation drawer fragment ?? i don't have this file just i have an activity_main.xml and drawer_list_item :( please more explication

Comment: @Mohamed Just visit this link and video. You will get all necessary information:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWpEh9k8i7Q&index=6&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD. 


If this helped you please accept the answer.

Comment: @Mohamed Did you check the link?

Comment: of course i checked but to do this thing i would change all my code that is not  good for me in this moment because i'm in hurry to finish my application which i will validate this night you understand me ? but if i have time for the next days i will do it and you notice that of course :)

Comment: OK sure. That video is very nice please see.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it following this sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- insert you main view childs here -->

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You will have your image added before the listview. You can manage your view like any other view.

Hope it will help you ;)