# Add header Image in navigation drawer on android studio sample navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

i need to add header image like this Post :

[can I add an image header in navigation drawer layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29029070/4707917)

but, im using android studio sample navigation drawer for doing this.

it is good or bad for design this ?

and the better way or Compact way for doing this ?

any suggestion ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can I add an Image Header in Navigation Drawer Layout?

Yes you can add with no problems.

If you use android studio navigation drawer or some thing else every thing are same. Some additional methods will be present and you need to check the methods required by you and delete other methods. You may also need to add few methods.

As per the latest android, best way of designing navigation drawer is by using recycler view and by using material design.

There are lot of materials in google for doing this, one of the finest tutorials I prefer is in the link given below you can have  a look:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWpEh9k8i7Q&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=6

Hope it helps.

Comment: i saw this videos, but there's not information about add image in header,anyway tnx

Comment: There is that is a complete tutorial check the next set of tutorials there is also about animation in navigation drawer, if you want about adding only image header check this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBKpsGar5mc&index=9&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD. If you want to learn and understand navigation drawer please visit 4 tutorials of navigation drawer.

Comment: Even check this, this will help you to achieve your objective: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byUM4vJdUMo&index=11&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Answer (score 0):

In the menudrawer activity setcontentview(layout).Inside this layout

try to add an imageview.My sample xml is as folllows

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->

         <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
       android:weightSum="7"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:id="@+id/parentlayoutt"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:orientation="vertical"

     >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
     android:id="@+id/headerimage"
  android:src="@drawable/yourimage"

/>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     android:id="@+id/parentmenuone"
     android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

      android:background="@color/pure_white"
    >

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/birdwhite"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:id="@+id/sidejive1"

         android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"          
            />


  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/sidejive1"
       android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:clickable="false"
       android:textColor="@color/violetbg"

       android:text="@string/createmenu"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     android:id="@+id/parentmenutwo"
      android:background="@drawable/whitebox"
    >

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profilewhite"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:id="@+id/sidejive2"
            android:clickable="false"


            android:layout_centerInParent="true"          
            />


  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/sidejive2"
       android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:clickable="false"
       android:textColor="@color/violetbg"

       android:text="@string/Accountmenu"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     android:id="@+id/parentmenuthree"
      android:background="@drawable/whitebox"
    >

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/homewhite"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:id="@+id/sidejive3"
          android:clickable="false"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"          
            />


  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/sidejive3"
       android:id="@+id/title3"
       android:textColor="@color/violetbg"

       android:text="@string/Dashboardmenu"
      android:clickable="false"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     android:id="@+id/parentmenufour"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:background="@drawable/whitebox"
    >

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/examplewhite"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:id="@+id/sidejive4"
          android:clickable="false"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"          
            />


  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/sidejive4"
       android:id="@+id/title4"
       android:textColor="@color/violetbg"

       android:text="@string/Examplemenu"
      android:clickable="false"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: tnx.and the better way and Compact way for doing this without this sample on android studio ?

Comment: this's the best way as it's put forward by the geeks themselves :) happy coding